# How do I compute the eigenfunctions of the Fourier Transform?

Tags: fourier-transform

I read today ([ref](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Fourier_transform#Eigenfunctions)) that the Continuous Fourier Transform has four eigenvalues: +1, +i, -1, and -i.   Associated with each eigenvalue is a space of eigenfunctions: functions which retain their form after undergoing the Fourier transform.  Perhaps the best known example is the Gaussian: the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is again Gaussian.

A more general example is the Hermite-Gauss functions (Gaussian multiplied by Hermite polynomial).  These are also eigenfunctions of the Fourier transform, which is why TEMxx modes (with Hermite-Gauss transverse profiles) are stable modes of laser beam propagation.

This leads me to wonder a number of things:

- How do I show that the Fourier transform has just these four eigenvalues?
- Given an arbitrary function, how do I find the projections onto the four eigenspaces?

Comment: Wouldn't math.stackexchange be a better place to ask this?

Comment: The fractionally iterated Fourier transform is useful in optics, for describing near-field diffraction.

Comment: For eigenvalues, just apply  Fourier four times to any function. You get the original back - eigenvalue 1.  Now find the fourth roots of that value.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have better luck on math.stackexchange.com, but here's a short outline of how to attack your problem.

- By definition, to calculate the eigenvalues of the Fourier transform, solve the equation 
  $$\mathcal{F}{f(x)} = \lambda f(x)$$
  or
  $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{-2\pi i X x} dx - \lambda f(x) = 0$$
- To decompose a function into Hermite-Gaussian functions $HG_n(x)$, i.e. find $c_n$ in
  $$f(x) = \sum_n c_n HG_n(x),$$
  take the inner product of $f(x)$ with each Hermite-Gauss function:
  $$c_n = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\overline{HG_n(x)} dx$$
  where $\bar{x}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $x$.

Disclaimer: this is all from memory, so please inform me of the inevitable mistakes, and I'll be glad to correct them.